# Inconsistent hover style for the "show activity" button

Tags: bug, status-review, design

If you hover the "show activity" button, its color is changed: (interestingly, the exact color differs between different sites)

[image: bad]

But if you hover the "save question" button next to it, it's not highlighted:

[image]

This is inconsistent. Both should have the same color.

Comment: Nice catch. As far as I can tell, the timeline icon changing color is the exception, no other link or button are changing colors when hovering. I'd guess a new developer made the timeline icon without knowing how the rest are behaving, and nobody ever noticed.

Comment: Also the horizontal position differs, for the timeline it is much closer to the icon than for the saves. Maybe if the color bug/inconsistency gets addressed then the positioning can be taken into account as part of the fix as well.